# Select 4 items with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've been reading about the Jquery UI selectable plugin, my question is:

Can I limit it to select only up to 4 items in a list ? Or maybe it would be easier to code it without using the selectable plugin ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for your answers, however I see that I didn't explain it very well: The user can select (ctrl + click) more than one item in a list by using the Jquery UI selectable plugin. What I want is to limit it so the users can only select up to 4 items (any of them).

Comment: +1 ! :) Now with the **edit** the question is more clear! I reedited my answer! look below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/t7evz/2/)

Look at the demo! 
And here is how to achieve it:

```
$('ul.list li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    if ($('.selected').length > 4) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        alert('You have already selected 4 items!\nYou can undo a selection.');
    }
});
```

*P.S.*

- Doing so you can toggle the already selected
  elements to select a NEW one!
- The
  `\n` inside the code is just
  for a New line inside the alert box ;)
  ;)

Comment: enhanced your solution a lil bit: [jsfiddle.net/hz6ka](http://jsfiddle.net/hz6ka/6/)

Comment: @Genzer ...well your solution is.... messy and does NOT allow a fully functional 'undo selected'. I reedited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily done by handling the jQuery UI selectable's selecting event.

The selectable plugin adds `ui-selecting` classes during the select operation. When the select operation finishes (i.e. you let go of the left mouse button), it turns all `ui-selecting` items to `ui-selected`. Other than that, nothing else is kept internally about the items that are to be selected.

This makes our job easier, whenever an item is turned into the `ui-selecting` state, the `selecting` event fires. In there we can count the total number of `.ui-selecting` and `.ui-selected` items, and if it's over the allowed limit, just remove the `ui-selecting` class from the current item.

This solution works on all select operations, single click, ctrl multi select and even bounding box selection.

```
$('ul').selectable({
    selecting: function(event,ui){
        // With the current item selected, are we over 4 items (the allowed maximum)?
        if($(this).find('.ui-selecting,.ui-selected').length > 4)
            // If yes, just remove it from the current selection
            $(ui.selecting).removeClass('ui-selecting');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vbbfs/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [:lt() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

`$('ul li:lt(4)')` selects 4 first `<li>` items in a list.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vjbzr/

Answer (score 1):

This should be done using the `:lt(index)` method.

for example `$('li:lt(4)')` will select all list elements with an index smaller than 4. And because the index is zero based, the first 4 elements will be selected.